# Show random image from product gallery as primary product image on Woocommerce shop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce variable product with multiple product images displayed in the product gallery. There is also the main product image set for the items.

I would essentially like the shop loops/archive pages to load a random image from the product gallery to display as the main product image on load.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried to find similar questions and found one at category level however it did not work for my requirements at product levels. There weren't any existing plugins that could achieve this either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to display random Product Image of distinct product\_cat in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448971/i-want-to-display-random-product-image-of-distinct-product-cat-in-woocommerce)

Comment: I did come across this question however it was for a specific category. Not all products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php -

```
function modify_woocommerce_product_get_image( $image, $product, $size, $attr ) {
    $image_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
    if( $image_ids ) {
        $image_ids = array_merge($image_ids, array($product->get_image_id()));
        $key = array_rand($image_ids);
        $id = $image_ids[$key];
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $size, false, $attr );
    }
    return $image;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_image', 'modify_woocommerce_product_get_image', 99, 4 );
```